# Kähler geometry: Computation of curvature tensor in normal coordinate w.r.t $g^{i\bar{j}}$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Tian’s book Canonical metrics in Kähler geometry, page 52-53 says:

> Assume that we have normal coordinates at the given point, so $g_{i\bar{j}}=\delta_{ij}$ and that the first order derivatives of $g$ vanish.

> …

> which we can rewrite after substituting  $$\frac{\partial^2g_{i\bar{j}}}{\partial z^k\partial \bar{z}^l}=-R_{i\bar{j}k\bar{l}} \text{ and } \frac{\partial^2g^{i\bar{j}}}{\partial z^k\partial \bar{z}^l}=R_{i\bar{j}k\bar{l}} $$ as…

I don’t understand the second equation, here is my computation:

$\frac{\partial^2g^{i\bar{j}}}{\partial z^k\partial \bar{z}^l}= \frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}^l}(\frac{\partial g^{i\bar{j}}}{\partial z^k})= \frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}^l} (-g^{i\bar{p}}\frac{\partial g_{q\bar{p}}}{\partial z^k}g^{q\bar{j}})= -g^{i\bar{p}}\frac{\partial^2 g_{q\bar{p}}}{\partial z^k\partial \bar{z}^l}g^{q\bar{j}}=-\frac{\partial^2 g_{j\bar{i}}}{\partial z^k\partial \bar{z}^l}=R_{j\bar{i}k\bar{l}}$.

Here $R_{i\bar{j}k\bar{l}}:= -\frac{\partial^2g_{i\bar{j}}}{\partial z^k\partial \bar{z}^l}+g^{p\bar{q}}\frac{\partial g_{p\bar{j}}}{\partial\bar{z}^l}\frac{\partial g_{i\bar{q}}}{\partial z^k}$, since I choose normal coordinate, the first order terms vanish.

Thanks.

Comment: Where did the penultimate equality come from?

Comment: @TedShifrin you mean the equality: $-g^{i\bar{p}}\frac{\partial^2 g_{q\bar{p}}}{\partial z^k\partial \bar{z}^l}g^{q\bar{j}}=-\frac{\partial^2 g_{j\bar{i}}}{\partial z^k\partial \bar{z}^l}$. In my comprehension, in normal coordinate, we have $g_{i\bar{j}}=\delta_{ij}$, thus by definition $g^{i\bar{j}}=\delta_{ij}$. $-g^{i\bar{p}}\frac{\partial^2 g_{q\bar{p}}}{\partial z^k\partial \bar{z}^l}g^{q\bar{j}}=-\delta_{ip} \frac{\partial^2 g_{q\bar{p}}}{\partial z^k\partial \bar{z}^l}\delta_{qj}= -\frac{\partial^2 g_{j\bar{i}}}{\partial z^k\partial \bar{z}^l}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin And (character limited) it seems that I need to switch the slot of i,j, according to the book. Wait, it occurs to me if I already use the normal coordinate, $g_{i\bar{j}}=g_{j\bar{i}}=\delta_{ij}$,  I can exchange i,j freely. As these computations origin from a globally defined expression, I always choose normal coordinate, this question doesn’t prevent me to get the correct result. Though the process confuses me a lot.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think I understand this question. Very helpful comment.